# allocation of load runner users with 4 cores and 4 GB RAM

Tags: loadrunner

I have an Web application and using Web protocol to record. Application configuration is 4 cores and 4 GB RAM. How many users can we allocate with 4 cores and 4 GB RAM.

Thanks
Raghav

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any idea.   I don't know anything about your virtual users or your application.  I don't know how much CPU, DISK, MEMORY, OR NETWORK they individually take to execute on load generators or how the resources are locked on the application. I don't know anything about your virtual user development skills - as a general rule people who are less mature with the tool produce virtual users which leverage far more resources than necessary.  You might have a scenario defined with no think time....you will get far fewer users on a server in such a case than you would with real users.  I don't know what your tolerances are for load generators resource use - I generally keep mine at no more than 50% of the available pool for any finite resource set.

But here is what I can share with you:

- Consider the use of at least three hardware matched load generators.  Use on for a control set of one virtual user of each type, with the remainder of your load balanced between the remaining two.   If all three degrade in response time, the the confidence is high you have a shared external cause in the app, but if your control group does not degrade but your global group does....well, you can see where this is going.
- Don't run your virtual users on your controller. Bad Magic
- High logging is like running a speedboat with a drag anchor...and that drag anchor is the contention on the disk as all of your virtual users write extensive logs to the drive.   Log on Error is sufficient.
- The answer of "how many" is why we test.  Your response time may degrade to the point of useful failure long before the host actually fails.
- Scalability is a function of how your resources are being used and how long you lock them up for a user.   Prematurely allocate large stuff that you hit a lot and then hold onto it for a long period, you will get far fewer users.

[image]

Have you considered the collective writings of Steve Souders?